# Can't Replace character ',' with '.'

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I want to replace comma with period.

I've tried 2 methods, but neither of them works.

Method 1:

```
if(evt.getKeyChar() == ','){ evt.setKeyChar('.');}
```

Method 2:

```
if(evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_COMMA){ evt.setKeyChar(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);}
```

I've tried to find something to help me but there are no such threads at all.

If you need more of the code I can add it but I don't really know if you guys need it so I did not add it.

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
// TODO add your handling code here:

char inte=evt.getKeyChar();

if (!(Character.isDigit(inte)|| inte == KeyEvent.VK_COMMA ||inte == KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD || inte==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || inte==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE){
if(evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_COMMA){ evt.setKeyChar(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);}
    getToolkit().beep();
    evt.consume();
}
}
```

Thats the whole thing that these lines i posted are in, im still new at java.So i'll let you guys deside.

Though the program gets the numbers and doesn't let anything else to be put inside except '.' and ',' but when i use , in a float number instead of . there are errors thats why i want to replavce it with '.'

Comment: what is the evt object

Comment: If you are trying to correct number inputs by users, why don't you let them input everything and replace the comma at the end? If that isn't what you are trying to do, please make your question clearer.

Comment: Are you sure the object instance where you run getKeyChar() is the same instance where you run setKeyChar()?

Comment: Don't write "solved" into the title. [Accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the correct answer is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `keyTyped` method:

**Adding the KeyListener**

```
tfield.addKeyListener(new KeyListeningTool());
```

**Code to Modify the KeyEvent**

```
class KeyListeningTool extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getKeyChar() == ',') {
            evt.setKeyChar('.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try it later and i'll inform you if it works where i need it.

Comment: @AlexPyrg: test his working code with text that you copy and paste into your JTextField, and then tell me if it still works. Try the same then using a DocumentFilter.

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels e-leet

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this works like a charm. Thanks for the time & effort you all guys put, to help me!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is actually an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely.

Never add a KeyListener to a JTextComponent as this can lead to dangerous side effects. Much better here is to use either a DocumentListener, added to the JTextField's Document or a DocumentFilter. The listener reacts after the document changes, and the filter reacts just before the document changes, allowing you to "filter" the changes before they occur.

If you want to change the text being entered into the JTextField, I suggest going the DocumentFilter route:

```
((PlainDocument) myJTextField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(....)
```

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class SwapCommaWithPeriod extends JPanel {
    private JTextField field = new JTextField(40);

    public SwapCommaWithPeriod() {
        add(field);

        ((PlainDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                text = text.replace(",", ".");
                super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
                    AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                text = text.replace(",", ".");
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SwapCommaWithPeriod mainPanel = new SwapCommaWithPeriod();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swap Comma With Period");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, im going to go on and tell you if this works for me, when i'll be able to get in my code.Thanks for taking the time to write and test all this man!